# Force RTL direction on specific ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know I can force the direction of my app using:

```
[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

My question is, can I force it only on one specific ViewController?

Comment: Havn’t tried it so am not sure. But could you set RTL before loading the view of your viewcontroller and then set it ot LTR when it is dismissed?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the code in swift, see the last line of code hope it suits yours need,

My understanding is if you want to set it to a specific VC then you have to assign sematic values to the views by using outlets,

```
  enum AppLanguages: String {
    case English = "en"
    case Thai = "th"
    case Arabic = "ar"
    case Tamil = "ta"

    var sematic : UISemanticContentAttribute {
        switch self {
        case .English,.Thai,.Tamil:
            return .forceLeftToRight
        case .Arabic:
            return .forceRightToLeft
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = AppLanguages(rawValue: "ar").sematic
```

or - if you like to change the buttons only or particular UI's only then,

```
UIButton.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

The above will change RTF for all uiview throughtout the application,

best practice is use a tableview to design the specific view and then reload it based on language changes it will work.

**For your specific views,**

```
self.yourView.semanticContentAttribute = AppLanguages(rawValue: "ar").sematic
```